# Find cell in html table containing a specific icon

Tags: r, rvest

I am looking for code that can inform me in which cell of an html table a particular icon resides. 
Here is what I am working with:

```
u <- "http://www.transfermarkt.nl/lionel-messi/leistungsdaten/spieler/28003/saison/2014/plus/1"
doc <- rvest::html(u)
tab <- rvest::html_table(doc, fill = TRUE)[[6]]
```

The column "Pos." designates the player's position in the field. Some of these have an additional icon. I can see the presence of these icons on the page as follows:

```
rvest::html_nodes(doc, ".kapitaenicon-table")
```

but this doesn't tell me WHERE they are. I would like my code to return that the icon occurs in rows 2, 10, 11, 27 of the "Pos. column" in the table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit more `rvest` and XPath magic can get you the indices:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(XML)

pg <- html("http://www.transfermarkt.nl/lionel-messi/leistungsdaten/spieler/28003/saison/2014/plus/1")

pg %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  extract2(6) %>% 
  html_nodes("tbody > tr") %>% 
  sapply(function(x) {
    length(xpathSApply(x, "./td[8]/span[@class='kapitaenicon-table icons_sprite']")) == 1
  }) %>% which

## [1]  2 10 11 27
```

That gets the 6th table, extracts the `tr`s then looks through them for an 8th `td` with the proper `span`/`class` in it. If the XPath search fails it returns an empty list, so you can use the length to determine which rows have the `td` with the icon in them and which do not.

This:

```
pg %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath="//table[6]/tbody/tr/td[8]") %>% 
  xmlSApply(xpathApply, "boolean(./span[@class='kapitaenicon-table icons_sprite'])") %>% 
  which
```

also works and it a bit tighter (and faster). It uses the XPath `boolean` operation to test for existence. This is handier if you have no other operations to perform on the node(s).

This is an `xml2` version, though I have to believe there has to be a better way to do this in `xml2`:

```
library(xml2)
library(magrittr)

pg2 <- read_html("http://www.transfermarkt.nl/lionel-messi/leistungsdaten/spieler/28003/saison/2014/plus/1")
pg2 %>% 
  xml_find_all("//table[6]/tbody/tr/td[8]") %>% 
  as_list %>% 
  sapply(function(x) {
    inherits(try(xml_find_one(x, "./span"), silent=TRUE), "xml_node")
  }) %>% which
```

**UPDATE**

For version `0.1.0.9000` of `xml2` I had to do the following:

```
pg2 %>% xml_find_all("//table") %>% 
  as_list %>% 
  extract2(6) %>% 
  xml_find_all("./tbody/tr/td[8]") %>% 
  as_list %>% 
  sapply(function(x) {
    inherits(try(xml_find_one(x, "./span"), silent=TRUE), "xml_node")
  }) %>% which
```

That should not be the case and I've [filed a bug report](https://github.com/hadley/xml2/issues/39).

```
Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
 system   x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
 ui       RStudio (0.99.441)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       America/New_York            

Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package    * version date       source        
 curl       * 0.5     2015-02-01 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
 devtools   * 1.7.0   2015-01-17 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
 magrittr     1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
 Rcpp       * 0.11.5  2015-03-06 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
 rstudioapi * 0.3.1   2015-04-07 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
 xml2         0.1.0   2015-04-20 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
```

Comment: awesome! The `XML` version works flawless, and it is very instructive.
However, something is off with the `xml2` solution, it returns an error ("argument to 'which' is not logical"). I think this may be caused by . `pg2 %>%   xml_find_all("//table[6]/tbody/tr/td[8]")` returning `{xml_nodeset (0)}`
Perhaps a typo somewhere?

Comment: I added the 2 `library` calls to the `xml2` version I used and re-ran the code in a clean environment and had no errors. I added my session info to the answer.

Comment: That's odd, I am still getting the same error and `pg2 %>% xml_find_all("//table[6]/tbody/tr/td[8]")` is still returning `{xml_nodeset (0)}` This causes the `as.list` to then return `list()`. I have the same version of R as you, the package versions are very close as well (identical or even more recent). I used a fresh session, to make sure the result wasn't affrected by other objects in my environment. Are you sure there isn't a typo somewhere? This is puzzling...

Comment: It was version `0.1.0.9000` that was causing the issue. Answer updated and filing a bug report.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it! That is indeed odd code. My version of xml2 was 0.1.0.9000, so that makes sense, Thanks for you help, I'll keep my eye out for a solution to the bug.