# Parse RSS Feeds with variable XML structures in R

Tags: xml, r, parsing, rss

I am a XML novice trying to scrape and parse the following RSS feed http://xml.newsbox.ch/corporate_web/che/dufry/digest_en_year_2015_atom.xml. Along this, I ran into two questions:

1) I would like to extract the nodes of individual news stories using `xmlChildren` on the parsed document as follows:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
xml.url <- "http://xml.newsbox.ch/corporate_web/che/dufry/digest_en_year_2015_atom.xml"
script <- getURL(xml.url)
doc <- xmlParse(script)
doc.children = xpathApply(doc,"//entry",xmlChildren)
```

Although this procedure works well on other feeds, where the individual news releases are stored with nodes `<items>`, it does not work in this particular case with nodes `<entry>` as it returns an empty list. I am stuck here, as I cannot figure out what I miss in the structure of the XML document.

2) More generally: Can I implement this approach to handle both cases when the XML structure includes the individual news stories either in node `<item>` or in node `<entry>` without knowing the particular structure in advance?

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to work with namespaces. Here are `XML` and `xml2` options:

```
# XML
ns <- xmlNamespaceDefinitions(doc, simplify=TRUE)
names(ns)[1] <- "x"
nodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "//x:entry", namespaces=ns)

# xml2
library(xml2)

XML_URL <- "http://xml.newsbox.ch/corporate_web/che/dufry/digest_en_year_2015_atom.xml"
doc <- read_xml(XML_URL)
ns <- xml_ns_rename(xml_ns(doc), d1="x")
xml_find_all(doc, "//x:entry", ns=ns)
```

Look at using the [boolean() XPath operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556130/find-cell-in-html-table-containing-a-specific-icon/30558163#30558163) to be able to handle multiple cases (i.e. the different feed formats).

Comment: Thank you, this works great! I didn't know about the boolean() XPath operator, but I think `xpathApply(doc, "boolean(//x:entry)",namespaces=ns)` does the job here.

Comment: For interest: `xpathApply(doc,“//x:entry“,xmlChildren, namespaces=ns)` works well. However, in [other cases](https://www.barry-callebaut.com/news/rss.xml), when `xpathApply(doc,“//item“,xmlChildren)` worked well, `xpathApply(doc,“//x:item“,xmlChildren, namespaces=ns)` returns an empty list. Is there a way to generally tell when to work with namespaces?

Comment: I suppose this behavior can be ascribed to default vs. non-default namespaces, as `xmlNamespaceDefinitions` returns `""` in the former case.

Answer (score 1):

This may not exactly answer your question, but did you consider using a ready-made package like [tm.plugin.webmining](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm.plugin.webmining/index.html)?

If you do not want to use the package, you can still inspect the code and see how they parsed the data.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to this package! I will definitely have a look at it.